# Is Laravel framework suitable for SMS bulk sending application

Tags: node.js, laravel, asynchronous, architecture, synchronous

Currently I have a project which built using Laravel framework.

- Now there is a requirement to integrate with a third party sms sending service call ideaBiz.
- I need to clarify whether this service should develop and deploy in 
  same Laravel application or separate application using Node.js - (since it is Asynchronous)
- According to my knowledge PHP is synchronous. so I have a doubt which it causes to generate unwanted delay to the current system functionalities.

Please assist on me this architectural issue.

Thanks

Comment: It very much depends on the use-case that you have if something like PHP is suitable for sending SMS in bulk. However I don't see much reason why PHP shouldn't be suitable for sending bulk.

Comment: I accept that it is suitable for sending bulk sms. But the issue is "Is it causes to generate unwanted delay to the current system functionalities" ???

Comment: It all depends on your server and the API on the other end. There is little way of giving decent feedback without knowing if the server is running decent hardware, if the network can handle a lot of data and if the API is capable of handling bulk as well.

Comment: Your question has little specifics on how much delay is acceptable, with that, using an API also adds risks out of your control, the API might be fast when you send a single request, but when you talk about bulk I expect 50K requests. Does the API handle bulk requests? Or would you have to send everything seperately?

Comment: API handls 5 request per second. So we have to add another delay on our side. and it is valid for every api types of that service.

Comment: You can use a cronjob perhaps to allow your server to start a separate process which will do all the API stuff. This will keep your normal application running as is without much problems (Also depending on the amount of data, how you create your cronjob, how much power your server has etc etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with Laravel without a problem! I suppose you just need to send a request to an api to do so?

I would recommend to take a look at [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) or [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) to execute these kinds of jobs. This way you can execute these request without impacting the web application itself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. In my case it needs to provide separate back-end for the admin and it includes Payment deduction(task scheduling), Subscriptions, Bulk SMS sending(Admin functionality) using api calls.

Comment: I would like to know isn't it causes to generate unwanted delay to the current system functionalities if we use queue for SMS???

Comment: It will not impact your application as long as you send the sms' using a queue or a scheduled task.